# Xamarin.Forms: DirectoryNoFoundException on WritingBytes

Tags: xamarin.forms

i download a video from a server as bytes and write those bytes as mp4 to the phones harddrive in pcl:

```
            byte[] stream = await VideoAPI.DownloadVideo(AdID);
            File.WriteAllBytes("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.interiorcircle/files/Movies/file.mp4", stream);
```

But this returns the following error:

(stream is not null)

```
{System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.interiorcircle/files/Movies/file.mp4".
```

But that doesnt make sense, since I am writing the file and path.

Where is this error comming from?

(Wiredly enough, while testing this worked once, but then not again)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the **Environment.SpecialFolder** to create a path, not a string variable.

```
byte[] stream = await VideoAPI.DownloadVideo(AdID);
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "file.mp4"); //also you can create extra folders
File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath , stream);
```

also, you can use different folders such as;

- Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos
- Environment.SpecialFolder.Personel
- Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
- Environment.SpecialFolder.Templates
- Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData
- Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic
- Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures
- Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts
- Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments
- Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop